# RazorEngineCore - How to use extension methods

Tags: razor

I am working with [`RazorEngineCore`](https://github.com/adoconnection/RazorEngineCore) and am coming across an issue where extension methods are not being identified properly. In my sample below, I am trying to use LINQ's single, and the error is:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List' does not contain a definition for 'First'

I've added the required assemblies using `AddAssemblyReferenceByName()` and assume it would load correctly. Yet I'm still getting the error.

Sample code:

```
class Program
{
    static string Content = @"
        Hello @Model.Name

        First item: @Model.Items.First();

        @foreach(var item in @Model.Items)
        {
            <div>- @item</div>
        }

        <div data-name=""@Model.Name""></div>

        <area>
            @{ RecursionTest(3); }
        </area>

        @{
            void RecursionTest(int level){
                if (level <= 0)
                {
                    return;
                }
                    
                <div>LEVEL: @level</div>
                @{ RecursionTest(level - 1); }
            }
        }";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IRazorEngine razorEngine = new RazorEngine();
        IRazorEngineCompiledTemplate template = razorEngine.Compile(Content,
            builder =>
            {
                builder.AddAssemblyReferenceByName("System.Collections");
                builder.AddAssemblyReferenceByName("System.Linq");
            });

        string result = template.Run(new
        {
                Name = "Alexander",
                Items = new List<string>()
                {
                        "item 1",
                        "item 2"
                }
        });

        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Edit: When I call the extension method fully qualified, it works. ie, calling System.Linq.First(myList) instead of myList.Single().

Comment: This is obviously pretty specific to RazorEngineCore. As the library doesn't have an especially large community established around it, I'm not certain you'll find much support for it here. It may be worth posting this as an issue on the GitHub page—and optionally referring back to this post. If you do get an answer there, be sure to share your findings here when you're done so that anyone running into a similar issue in the future can quickly find the answer.

Comment: That said, as a quick check, did you try adding `@using System.Linq` at the top of your `Content` variable? I'm not sure if RazorEngineCore accepts Razor directives at the top, but it's worth trying to ensure that the namespace is properly in scope.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy! I didn't have enough reputation to create the tag. I did try adding @using and it still failed. One interesting bit is if I call the extension method fully qualified, it works. ie, instead of myList.Single() System.Linq.First(myList). I'll post an issue on the GitHub page. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Well, in ASP.NET you can't do that either. Its because you cant call extension methods on dynamic objects:

```cs
public IActionResult Index1()
{
    return View(new List<string>()
    {
        "item 1",
        "item 2"
    });
}
```

```cs
@model dynamic

<div class="text-center">
    @foreach (var item in @Model.First())
    {
        <div>- @item</div>
    }
</div>
```

will throw

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
RuntimeBinderException: 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'First'
```

You have to either cast dynamic to IEnumerable or use strongly typed model.

See unit test:
https://github.com/adoconnection/RazorEngineCore/blob/ccbb5b2ca51dd18afc700fbc8732ad491f4fd7ef/RazorEngineCore.Tests/TestCompileAndRun.cs#L645